# Start an App right after login - Mono / Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, mono, debian, startup, init.d

I tried many different ways to add an executable (winforms) created in C# using mono to start automatically after login, but any attempt was not right.

Does anyone know how can I do it? I'm running a Raspbian (Raspberry Pi).

Thanks since now!

Answer (score 2):

I guess your idea was to launch the app in the desktop, but if you need it as a "kiosk", I always use:

Steps to configure the Raspberry Pi to run as a kiosk with the presentation

**Software setup**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install mono-complete xutils
```

**To avoid the screen turning off**

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

And now in the editor, append:

```
setterm -blank 0 -powersave off -powerdown 0
xset s off
xset -dpms s off
mono /path/to/your/assembly.exe
```

**Auto start as kiosk**

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

And now in the editor, replace contents with:

```
/bin/bash startx &
exit 0
```

Make sure that in `sudo raspi-config` start mode is configured as *console*

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution. I created a myprogram.desktop and I added it to the directory /home/pi/.config/autostart. Please make sure if it exists. If don't, it is needed to create a folder called **autostart** and add the file there.

The myprogram.desktop should looks like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=myprogram
Type=Application
Comment=It runs my app.
Exec=/home/pi/myprogram.exe
```